# ActionScript - Class Extends Object?

Tags: actionscript, object

i've been poking around RIM's PlayBook SDK and noticed they extend Object on a lot of their classes.

are there benefits to extending Object on a custom class that would normally be unextended?

```
package qnx.notificationManager
{
    public class Notification extends Object
    {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify that your class extends another class, the compiler automatically makes your class extend `Object`.  So the answer is that you don't gain any benefit; they must have just been trying to be explicit, or maybe the code was generated through decompilation.

Comment: i decompiled the SWC's main library.swf to have a look.  so it's probably the decompiler that caused that.  interesting.